# undefined method ` @' in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Does someone know why

```
hash['City'] = {}
hash['City']['answer0'] = 'foo'
```

Get the following error:

```
undefined method `+@' for {"answer0"=>"foo"}:Hash
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you initialize the hash first like `hash = {}` ?

Comment: You are not showing the line you get the error

Comment: Can you add a stack trace of where this error occurs? It is not happening at the assignment here but somewhere else.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. Post more code?

Comment: I think you messed up at hash initialization

Comment: `+@` is the method for the unary plus operator so you're doing `+hash['City']` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have 'multi-dimentional' hashes you need to properly define the hash like so:

```
a = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new(&hash.default_proc) }
```

Then you can do:

```
a['city']['answer0'] = 'foo'
```